# Bulk converting JPEG and MP4 into HEIC

Tags: video, mp4, converter

is there a way to batch/bulk convert JPEG and MP4 files to HEIF/HEIC? There are a lot of tools to convert in the other direction one by one.

I want to convert all files on a Windows system.

Thank you.